# PHP DOM replace element with a new element

Tags: php, dom

I have a DOM object with loaded HTML markup. I'm trying to replace all embed tags that look like this:

```
<embed allowfullscreen="true" height="200" src="path/to/video/1.flv" width="320"></embed>
```

With a tag like this:

```
<a 
href="path/to/video/1.flv" 
style="display:block;width:320px;height:200px;" 
id="player">
</a>
```

I'm having troubles figuring this out and I don't want to use regular expression for this. Could you help me out?

EDIT:

This is what I have so far:

```
         // DOM initialized above, not important
            foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('embed') as $e) {
                $path = $e->getAttribute('src');
          $width = $e->getAttribute('width') . 'px';
          $height = $e->getAttribute('height') . 'px';
          $a = $dom->createElement('a', '');
          $a->setAttribute('href', $path);
          $a->setAttribute('style', "display:block;width:$width;height:$height;");
          $a->setAttribute('id', 'player');
          $dom->replaceChild($e, $a); // this line doesn't work
      }
```

Comment: Don't have time to write up an answer right now, but check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: I have looked but I cannot figure it out. I have updated my answer with the code I already have but the last line which is supposed to switch elements does not work.

Comment: See similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17864378

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It's easy to find elements from a DOM using `getElementsByTagName`. Indeed you wouldn't want to go near regular expressions for this.

If the DOM you are talking about is a PHP `DOMDocument`, you'd do something like:

```
$embeds= $document->getElementsByTagName('embed');
foreach ($embeds as $embed) {
    $src= $embed->getAttribute('src');
    $width= $embed->getAttribute('width');
    $height= $embed->getAttribute('height');

    $link= $document->createElement('a');
    $link->setAttribute('class', 'player');
    $link->setAttribute('href', $src);
    $link->setAttribute('style', "display: block; width: {$width}px; height: {$height}px;");

    $embed->parentNode->replaceChild($link, $embed);
}
```

Edit re edit:

```
$dom->replaceChild($e, $a); // this line doesn't work
```

Yeah, `replaceChild` takes the new element to replace-with as the first argument and the child to-be-replaced as the second. This is not the way round you might expect, but it is consistent with all the other DOM methods. Also it's a method of the parent node of the child to be replaced.

(I used `class` not `id`, as you can't have multiple elements on the same page all called `id="player"`.)

Comment: "_Also it's a method of the parent node of the child to be replaced._" - 

this ended my 40 minutes of debugging session. Thanks!

Comment: If you try to replace DOM elements within a foreach loop then elements will be skipped because you are altering a "live" object. Iterating backwards, converting the node list to an array, or using a while loop based on the node list length are a few ways to solve that issue.

Comment: You saved my day!! I was looking for this in my dreams all the night.

Comment: Since PHP 8 this is possible:  `$embed->replaceWith($link);`