# Replace html tags and pass to function in php

Tags: php, str-replace

I have an HTML file that has external assets on a secure server that needs a url generated in order to load. I can load the HTML file fine, but none of the images will load. Relative paths wont work. I need to pass the image `src` attribute to my `generateURL` method and replace the current relative `src` paths with my generated url. An example HTML file I need to replace the tags in would be:

```
<img id="Im0" src="slide1page1/img/1/Im0.png" alt="Im0" width="720" height="540" style="display: none" />
<img id="Im1" src="slide1page1/img/1/Im1.png" alt="Im1" width="136" height="60" style="display: none" />
<img id="Im2" src="slide1page1/img/1/Im2.png" alt="Im2" width="669" height="45" style="display: none" />
```

My php script that I load the page through is:

```
<?php
function generateURL($target,$seconds)
{
    $secret = "mysecretpasscode";
    $end    = time() + $seconds;
    $url    = $target . "?e=" . $end;
    $toHash = $secret . $url;
    $secure = $url . "&h=" . md5($toHash);
    return $secure;
}
$id     = $_POST['id'];
$loc    = $_POST['loc'];
$url    = $loc . "slide" . $id . ".html";
$secure = generateURL($url,600); 
$page   = file_get_contents($secure);
?>
```

if I `echo $page`, I can see the page as if I just loaded an html page (but no images). What I need to do before that is find all the `src` tags in the HTML and run them through my `generateURL` method so I can generate the correct URL with proper hashing to load. I am thinking a `str_replace` will work, but I am not familiar enough with `regex` to continue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use PHP DOM instead?  Then you can just select the images using xpath.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php

Comment: I am not familiar with this. I am seeing a lot of XML references. This looks like it may be doing something that I would want: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php#73557 . I will try and find more examples, but if you have a simple one of what I am wanting to do that'd be great

Comment: ok I am making progress! I am at this point where I have selected all the tags and generated new URLs...How do I replace them now? http://pastie.org/2885066

Comment: ok I am doing `$dom->replaceChild($new,$old)` in the loop and then after the loop I do `echo $dom->saveHTML();` and I get a blank screen. `$old` is `$old = $image->getAttribute('src');`, `$new` is `$new = generateURL($loc . $old, 600);`...not sure why I am getting a blank screen

Comment: Check this thread out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194875/php-dom-replace-element-with-a-new-element

Comment: alright that link helped..I just ended up replacing the whole `img` tag how he replace his embed tags. I'm just running into some html encoding issues, the character `...` is displaying weird

Answer (score 0):

First have a look at this answer: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Though I think you could use PHP's `preg_replace_callback` as follows:

```
src_regex = "/src=\"([^\"]+\/";
preg_replace_callback(src_regex, generateURL, html);
```

Do take into account that the second parameter (`generateURL`) must be a function with only a single argument, take a look at [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html).

Answer (score 0):

A html parser would be better. Provided you've selected all the tags, you can extract the relative path with the function below.

```
$u = '<img id="Im0" src="slide1page1/img/1/Im0.png" alt="Im0" width="720" height="540" style="display: none" />';
$v = explode(" ", $u);
$x = explode("=", $v[2]);
echo str_replace("\"", "", $x[1]);
```

Outputs

```
slide1page1/img/1/Im0.png
```