# How to use php dom document to remove and replace tags

Tags: php, image, dom

I have image tag `<img src="path_to_file.png">` but I want that the image tag be converted to link in mobile site.
So I want img to be converted to an href:

```
<a href="path_to_file.png" target="_blank">Click here to open in new tab</a>
```

I am getting started with php dom.
I could get all the attribute listed.

```
$newdocument = new DOMDocument();
$newdocument->loadHTML();
$getimagetag = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach($getimagetag as $tag) {
    echo $src=$tag->getAttribute('src');
}
```

But how do we get the src attribute , then remove the img tag completely because it contains other parameter like height and length and then create new tag of link?

Hi guys I could get it done from php dom using following code

```
$input="<img src='path_to_file.png' height='50'>";
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($input);
    $imageTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
    foreach($imageTags as $tag) {
        $src=$tag->getAttribute('src'); 
        $a=$doc->createElement('a','click here to open in new tab');
        $a->setAttribute('href',$src);
        $a->setAttribute('style','color:red;');
        $tag->parentNode->replaceChild($a,$tag);
        } 
        $input=$doc->saveHTML();
echo $input;
```

The create element can also be used to put text between `<a></a>` ie Click...new tab.

replacechild is used to remove $tag i.e. `img` and replace it with `a` tag.
By setting attribute, we can add other parameters like style,target etc.

I used php dom in the end because I only wanted the data that I get from mysql to be converted and not the other elements like logo of website. Ofcourse it can be possible using javascript too.

Thanks

@dave chen for  javascript way and pointing to detecting mobile link.

@nate for pointing me to a answer.

Comment: Check out this duplicate-like solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3195048/2609094

Comment: hi thanks for the code...but I wanted to ask that how do I input text _click here to open in new tab_ between the **<a href="path_to_file.png"></a>**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend doing this with JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Images Test</title>
    <script>
        window.onload = changeImages;

        function changeImages() {
            var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

            while (images.length > 0) {
                var imageLink       = document.createElement("a");
                imageLink.href      = images[0].src;
                imageLink.innerHTML = "Click here to view " + images[0].title;
                images[0].parentNode.replaceChild(imageLink, images[0]);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Here is a image of flowers  : <img src="images/flowers.bmp"   title="Flowers"  ><br>
    Here is a image of lakes    : <img src="images/lakes.bmp"     title="Lakes"    ><br>
    Here is a image of computers: <img src="images/computers.bmp" title="Computers"><br>
</body>
</html>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/JMRqJ/)

Comment: Hi thanks!I had completely forgotten javascript can be used too!

Comment: I would like to point to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/javascript-solution-to-detect-mobile-browser for detecting mobile, and switch your tags based on this.

Answer (score 3):

Use phpQuery, it's amazing. It's just like using jquery! :)
https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/