# How do you convert one to many images in a text field to links pointing to alternate images?

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

The data will look like this:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam turpis pede, vulput ate a, porta at, venenatis in, mi.</p>
<img alt="" src="images/blue.T.jpg" style="width: 480px; height: 320px; text-align:left;" />
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec consequat luctus felis.</p>
<img alt="test" src="images/red_300x225.jpg" style="padding: 10px; width: 300px; height: 225px;" title="whatever" />
<p>Yadda yadda...</p>
<img alt="test" src="images/green_small.jpg" style="padding: 10px; width: 600px; height: 360px;" title="whatever" />
<p>That's all folks...</p>
```

The goal:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam turpis pede, vulput ate a, porta at, venenatis in, mi.</p>

<a href='images/blue.L.jpg'  class='fancybox' title='$title' rel='none'>
<img alt="" src="images/blue.T.jpg" style="width: 480px; height: 320px; text-align:left;" />
</a>

<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec consequat luctus felis.</p>

<a href='images/red.L.jpg'  class='fancybox' title='$title' rel='none'>
<img alt="test" src="images/red_300x225.jpg" style="padding: 10px; width: 300px; height: 225px;" title="whatever" />
</a>

<p>Yadda yadda...</p>

<a href='images/green.L.jpg'  class='fancybox' title='$title' rel='none'>
<img alt="test" src="images/green_small.jpg" style="padding: 10px; width: 600px; height: 360px;" title="whatever" />
</a>

<p>That's all folks...</p>
```

The purpose is to add a fancybox lightbox to images that have been saved with the text field. With the guide of another post I figured out how to convert the original image(s) to the new image filename for the link, but not yet how to loop through and substitute the new linked images in the source.

The  could be arranged in different order, varying styles, etc. What I have so far is a method of extracting the image filename and converting it to the new name which is what I need for the . Here is what I have to convert the images and obtain the new filename:

$text = ($row['fulltext']); // text with images is stored in a mysql text field

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML("$text");
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach($tags as $tag)
{
  $source = $tag->getAttribute('src');

  $target = str_replace ( ".T.jpg", ".L.jpg", "$source" );
  $target = str_replace ( "_small.jpg", ".L.jpg", "$source" );
  $target = preg_replace('/_[^_.]*\./', '.', $source); // grabs everything including and after last underscore
  $new_img_html = "<a href='images/$target'  class='fancybox' title='...' rel='none'>$original_img_html</a>";

  // $original_img_html - the img src html for each image, something like
  // <img alt="test" src="images/green_small.jpg" style="padding: 10px; width: 600px; height: 360px;" title="whatever" />

  $replace = preg_replace('$original_img_html', "$new_img_html", $text);
}
```

What I don't get is to to create set up a preg_replace to find each image and grab the complete  so that I can surround it with the link code for each image. Simplified:

Change:

```
<img src='whatever'>
```

To:

```
<a href='whatever' class='fancybox'>
<img src='whatever'>
</a>
```

If necessary, I can put up a demo link.

Comment: Why aren't you doing this on the client side with Javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194875/php-dom-replace-element-with-a-new-element

Comment: PHP solution is the goal. Don't need to account for clients who disable javascript, minimal or not.

Comment: @Catatonic you win this battle?